# Why is there a gear icon and not my app's logo on iOS Facebook permission confirm screen?

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, facebook-apps, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm requesting "public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday", "user_location" information from my iPhone app users' and on my Facebook app settings, I've configured my app's 1024 x 1024 logo. When the app asks for the first time permission, my app's logo is visible on the permission confirm screen of Facebook web login. In the consequent permission requests, Facebook SDK shows the confirm page as shown here, but now there's this gear icon instead of my app's icon and the user's profile photo.

In another app of mine, this doesn't happen and I can always see the app's icon and the user's profile photo. I compared their settings but couldn't catch the difference. I must be missing something but I can't figure it out.

I'm using Facebook-iOS-SDK v3.14.

Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: When did you create your FB App?, it may take some time to be in effect, I guess.

Comment: I created the app months ago, but I configured the app icon yesterday. The weird thing is that the app icon and the user's profile photo appears on the very first permission request but not on the consecutive ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like facebook intended this behavior after their latest SDK release.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/317451798411754/) I've found the related facebook bug report and they have closed it as "By Design". According to a member of the Facebook Platform Team :

> This is by design. The confirmation dialog does not serve the app icon, but instead uses an non-app specific icon.

Comment: Oh, now it all makes sense. Thank you!